# Range of $ \frac{x}{(x-2)(x+1)} $

Tags: calculus, functions

Find Range of $$ y =\frac{x}{(x-2)(x+1)} $$

Why is the range all real numbers ?

the denominator cannot be $0$ Hence isn't range suppose to be $y$ not equals to $0$ ?

Comment: A fraction is $0$ when the _numerator_ is $0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The range is $\mathbb R$ because for every $y\in\mathbb R$, there exists some $x$ such that $$\frac{x}{(x-2)(x+1)}=y.$$

For example, for $y=0$, you have $$\frac{0}{(0-2)(0+1)}=\frac{0}{(-2)\cdot 1} = -\frac{0}{2}=0.$$

---

For a general $y$, you have to show that the equation above has a solution, which you can try to do by multiplying it by $(x-2)(x+1)$ to get

$$x=yx^2 - yx - 2y$$

This can be further simplified to a quadratic equation, and it's fairly easy to see if a quadratic equation has a solution

(*Hint:* it has something to do with the discriminant).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively: the function can be expressed as the sum:
$$y =\frac{x}{(x-2)(x+1)}=\frac13\left(\frac{2}{x-2}+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)=\frac13\left(g(x)+h(x)\right)$$
The functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are hyperbolas with the range $g\ne0$ and $h\ne0$. And the function $y$ has the range in $\mathbb{R}$, in particular, $y(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this range is more properly $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ which is the Extended Real Number line ( or the [Affinely Extended Real Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffinelyExtendedRealNumbers.html) if you prefer ) and not $\mathbb{R}$.

$\mathbb{R}$ does not include $\pm\infty$ and at the two poles ( $x=-1$ and $x=2$ ) this function can be said to take on these "values".

$\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ does include these values.